# boost::socket receives only one message

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

I am writing simple server using `boost::asio`.
Currently I have ready part of the server that receives data.
But I have problem. `Boost::asio` receives only one message (my client program sends multiple  number of messages).

After receiving message I must do something to be able to receive another message from the same client?

```
TCPConnection::TCPConnection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
                            : socket_(io_service),
                              socketActive(true)
{
    Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: TCPConnection::TCPConnection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) : socket_(io_service)";
}

void TCPConnection::Start()
{
  Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: void TCPConnection::Start()";


  socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
      boost::bind(&TCPConnection::HandleRead, shared_from_this(),
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void TCPConnection::HandleRead(const boost::system::error_code& e,
    std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: void TCPConnection::HandleRead(const boost::system::error_code& e, std::size_t bytes_transferred)";

  if (!e)
  {
    Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: New message";    

    Message tempMessage;
    tempMessage.CopyData((boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection>)this, buffer_.data());
    messageQueue->PushBack(tempMessage);
  }
  else if (e != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
  {
    Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: Close connection";
    this->Stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: tcp doesn't speak in messages. It speaks in streams of data.

Comment: Well you only call `async_read_some` once, so that should come as no surprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you successfully read data, you need to request the `io_service`/`socket` to once again handle a data read. My usual solution looks like this:

```
void handle_read(asio::error_code ec, size_t bytes_read) {
    if(!ec) {
        /*Do Stuff*/
        socket.async_read(/*buffer*/, handle_read);
    } else {
        /*Error handling*/
    }
}
```

I haven't syntax checked the code I'm providing here, but you should get the right idea.

Comment: But it looks like it is recursive method? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @RomanNowak It certainly *looks* recursive, but it's not. `async_read_some` is a function that returns immediately. The function you pass it is then invoked by whichever thread is running processes on behalf of `io_service` when the OS reports that it has received data. No recursion is invoked.

Comment: @jfly you tagged the wrong person; I provided the answer, not the question.

Comment: @Xirema my fault:)